# MOTD not displayed after installing openssh from source

Tags: debian, ubuntu, ssh, openssh, motd

On Debian Wheezy the default openssh server package displays the motd from /etc/motd. 
When i compile it from source (openssh-6.0p1) it won't display the motd anymore after an ssh login.
Configure options:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh  --with-pam  --with-md5-passwords --with-kerberos5 --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/run/sshd
```

- **UsePAM yes** is enabled
- No configs have been overwritten. Only the sshd binary.
- **pam_motd.so** is loaded in the sshd process
- source is from ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/
- source from **apt-get source openssh** works and displays the motd. It was compiled with the same configure arguments.

Which source parts are responsible for that difference?

This also applies to my Ubuntu machine.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: in the `sshd_config` file, probably under `/etc/sshd`, if you search for `PrintMotd`, what do you see ?

Comment: PrintMotd yes/no doesn't affect the behavior on debian. Configs aren't changed btw

Comment: can you see if selinux is preventing the sshd binary from reading /etc/motd? maybe it's trying, but is being prevented

Comment: where do you install the built version? How do you start the server? Did you include the [patches](http://sources.debian.net/patches/summary/openssh/1:7.1p2-2/) from Debain package?

Comment: Do you have `Banner` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` uncommented and pointing at `/etc/motd` while `PrintMotd` is enabled ?

Comment: /usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sshd usr/sbin/sshd     - just like the default sshd. newer version (just tried 7.1) show the motd, but i have to use older ones and have to find the source location that's responsible for it. thx so far